# Sylius: 504 Gateway Time-out on dev environment with Standard-Edition

Tags: php, symfony, nginx, sylius

I've followed the installation steps here: http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/book/installation.html

Everything it's ok until I don't try to access the /app_dev.php.

I'm running it on Vagrant v1.8.1 with a Ubuntu 14.04 box, memory=1024 and cpus=2. The physical host is a MacbookPro 10.11.3 (i5 2.7 GHz, Ram 8 Gb).

Even tried to install apcu extension and changing the memory_limit in php.ini file to 512 Mb but nothing changes.

Nginx logs says:

> 2016/03/16 11:31:06 [error] 1292#0: *1 upstream timed out (110:
>   Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream,
>   client: 192.168.10.1, server: test.dev, request: "GET /app_dev.php/
>   HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "test.dev",
>   referrer: "http://test.dev/app_dev.php/login"

The application log doesn't show any error. Also tried to reprovision the vm and install Sylius from start but I get always the same behavior.

I think it's related to the host configuration but don't know where to start.

Comment: do you have any other working symfony project in vagrant running? If you don't try a test symfony empty project - because this can be symfony related and not sylius. http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html

Comment: @nakashu Yes, I have a base install of Symfony 3.0.3. No timeout errors are shown.

Comment: If you think your issue is related to your host configuration, it would be a good start if you showed your actual configuration.

Comment: @xabbuh: with "host" configuration I mean something general that could be vagrant itself or nginx or php-fpm. As soon as I can will update the answer with mi vagrant file. For now this is the nginx config: https://wecodepixels.com/nginx-configuration-for-sylius/

Answer (score 0):

After many attempt with different box configuration I finally managed to make Sylius working. Just removed and reinstalled plugin vagrant-bindfs.

It's still really slow and use much memory (about 60MB), I will dig more on NFS configuration for Vagrant-OSX and then I will update this answer.